# how to change css style for every second data (picture) from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Is there any chance when reading data from MySQL database to apply PHP code so every second record will have something different(different css code ).

For example: I am using images like this for my comment system.
http://prntscr.com/3hpiep

Every image is in a circle shape, but I want every second image to have a circle shape and others should a square shape.

Can this be done?

http://prntscr.com/3hplgr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
.myclass:nth-child(even) {/* round style */}
.myclass:nth-child(odd) {/* square style */}
```

as long as they share a common parent element.

If you have a deeper structure, you may need to use the selector somewhere higher up the tree,  e.g.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="comment_image"><img .../></div>
    <div class="comment_image"><img .../></div>
</div>
```

You would want

```
.comment_image:nth-child(even) img {/* round style */}
.comment_image:nth-child(odd) img {/* square style */}
```

(although in this example you could also apply the style to the div - this is just to illustrate the hierarchy)

From the PHP code you pasted in the comments below, it seems you have a structure like

```
<div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="comment_box"><div><img/></div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="comment_box"><div><img/></div>...</div>
...
</div>
```

Which means you actually want to apply the round style to the image in every fourth div inside the outer div, starting with the second. Phew! Here's the CSS for that:

```
.comment_box img {/* square style */}
.comment_box:nth-child(4n+2) img {/* round style */}
```

Comment: depends. That's correct if .comment_image is your parent element, but if that class is on each image, you want img.comment_image:nth-child(...) instead. Or nth-of-type if there are other elements inside the same parent

Comment: if that's not working for you the most likely scenario is you have something like <div><img/></div>  <div><img></div> - if you add a snippet of the HTML output to your question it would help

Comment: Here is php code i am using to display images and other stuffs http://prntscr.com/3hpzsn, and i also changed my css code to http://prntscr.com/3hq0e6.

Comment: Right, the problem is that the image is always the first child of its parent. So you need to use the selector on comment_box. Furthermore, you actually want every fourth child of the parent to be round, not every second, because you have your spacing divs in between. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter inside your loop.

```
if($counter%2==0) 
   {//Even}
else
   { // Odd}
```

Comment: So the only one image (second row) will have round style correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-child even and odd selectors. Place each image in one same tag (like `<li>` or `<div>`) and in css use

```
your-tag:nth-child(even) {/* round style */}
your-tag:nth-child(odd) {/* round style */}
```

Comment: But when i use that code every image is in square shape.http://prntscr.com/3hpv93

Comment: I reviewed your code and get that the images in one file (here is your code <img class="image__pic js-image-pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/ks2k8Bn.png" alt="" id="screenshot-image"> ks2k8Bn.png file is one file with 4 images).  You should add each image in one <img> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while cycle to iterate over results from a database query. In the while cycle you decide whether the current iteration is even or odd. If the current iteration is odd, then add odd class to the element, if the current iteration is even, then add even class to the element.

I wrote a simple example which uses PDO library for working with database:

```
echo '<div class="items">';
$isOdd = false;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div class="' . (($isOdd) ? 'odd' : 'even') . '"><img src="" /></div>';
    $isOdd = !$isOdd;
}
echo '</div>';
```

The result of the cycle will be:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="odd"><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="even"><img src="" /></div>
</div>
```

Another way how to achieve the same result is to use `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` in CSS:

```
.items div:nth-child(even) {
    /* Properties */
}

.items div:nth-child(odd) {
    /* Properties */
}
```

Comment: Well this looks too complicated for me.I learn php just few days.I thought thwre would be some easier way.

Comment: @Crion The easier way is only with CSS. With PHP all ways will look similar to this one.

Comment: I would use any way, i just want to make it working.I used this code but then every image gets in square shape.http://prntscr.com/3hpryu